# React-redux dispatch action and useSelector does not work on android/ios

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

User enter value. Value is saved in local storage. I have put the `console.log to` and i can see the action is being dispatched and I can read value as well using useSelector. But strangely It is not working on **iPhone 14**  ios **16.x** and some newer android devices **os version 13**. Neither `console.log` run nor I can read the value using useSelector. in case of above mentioned devices. I tried to change key and storage in store file but they don't seems to work.

My suspicion could be of configuration of store.

**Package Versions**

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.66.4",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
"react-redux": "^7.2.6",
"redux": "^4.1.2",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
```

**Store file**

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {name as appName} from '../../app.json';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',                //tried to change with primary
  whitelist: ['userReducer'],
  keyPrefix: appName,
  storage: AsyncStorage,      //tried to change with redux storage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export default () => {
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
      getDefaultMiddleware({
        immutableCheck: false,
        serializableCheck: {
          ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
        },
      }),
  });
  let persistor = persistStore(store, [{manualPersist: true}]);
  return {store, persistor};
};
```

**Login file**

```
const {number, chat} = useSelector(store => store.userReducer);
const [num, setNum] = useState('')

dispatch({
  type: 'SET_EMPTY_CHAT',
});

dispatch({
  type: 'SET_NUMBER',
  payload: num
});
```

Dispatch function being called in login function and console.log runs inside login function.

**UserReducer File**

```
import {createReducer} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  chat: [],
  number: ''
};

export const userReducer = createReducer(initialState, {
  SET_EMPTY_CHAT: (state, action) => {
    const {payload} = action;
    console.log('SET_EMPTY_CHAT called');
    state.chat = [];
  },

  SET_NUMBER: (state, action) => {
    const {payload} = action;
    console.log('SET_NUMBER called');
    state.number = payload;
  }
})
```

Comment: Does it work if you are not using `redux-persist` at all?

Comment: I tried to set serializableCheck to false rather than ignoring actions. It still not working.

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the code you've posted. Are there any error logs? What debugging steps have you taken to diagnose this issue?

Comment: No error logs while dispatching/reading. They just simply don't run. One possibility is that it is not waiting for action and just go forward.

Comment: *What* isn't run? What actions are there to wait on? All the actions you've shown are synchronous.

Comment: @CopyPaste it's not about disabling a check or warning. If it doesn't work, remove parts until it does. Right now, the only operating-system-specific thing in your stack is `AsyncStorage`, so for a change don't persist your reducer and see if it works. Then you know what's causing the problem.

Comment: @phry Yes you were right about AsyncStorage. I was using `"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.7"` and now update it to latest version and i had to change key to 'primary' as well. Thanks a bunch!